# NArgMax returns not a number error

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following code:

```
rho2[r2_, h2_, t2_] := r2 - t2 + p + h2 ;(*10-2+2+1=11*)
rho1[r1_, h1_, t1_] := r1 - t1 + p + h1;(*10-2+2+2=12*)
V[b1_?NumericQ, b2_?NumericQ] := (rho1[r1, h1, t1] - p)*d + 
   Integrate[
    Integrate[
     rho2[r2, h2, t2]*(b2*z2) - 
      rho1[r1, h1, t1]*(d - b1*z1)*
       PDF[LogMultinormalDistribution[{mu1, 
          mu2}, {{sig1^2, sig1*sig2*w}, {sig1*sig2*w, sig2^2}}], {z1, 
         z2}], {z2, 0, (d - b1 *z1)/b2}, 
     Assumptions -> {b1, b2, z1, d} \[Element] Reals], {z1, 0, d/b1}, 
    Assumptions -> {b1, b2} \[Element] Reals] - (b1 + h1)*
    b1*(Exp[mu1 + sig1^2/2]) - (b2 + h2)*b2*(Exp[mu2 + sig2^2/2]);

With[{d = 10, mu1 = 1, mu2 = 2, sig1 = 0.2, sig2 = 0.5, w = 0, h1 = 1,
   h2 = 1, p = 2, t1 = 2, t2 = 2, r1 = 10, r2 = 10}, 
 NArgMax[{V[b1, b2], b1 >= 0 && b2 >= 0}, {b1, b2}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 10]]
```

I am trying to find the optimal solutions to b1 and b2 for the function V[b1, b2] using the NArgMax function. When I run the code it gives me not a number error as follows:

NArgMax::nnum: The function value -40.1014 is not a number at {b1,b2} = {1.918621215,1.716688753}. But this looks like that Mathematica already found a solution, right?

It also runs very slow even to give me one data point, I am not even trying to get a plot yet but that is ultimately what I would like to do.How can I make it run faster? How can I change the integrals as they take a very long time.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you simplify your code? I tried evaluating it and it just sat there for a long time churning away. If you can give a reproducible example that does not take that long to calculate (e.g. eliminate the plotting portion and focus on a single value that reproduces your problem), you may get more help.

Comment: Defining several constants at the beginning of your code and then attempting to redefine them temporarily later (using `With`) probably is not a good idea, because some of the original values may already be embedded in the functions defined in the meantime.  Also, since most of the run time is consumed by repeatedly evaluating the double integrals, you should focus your efforts are increasing the speed of those integrals, which certainly is possible.

Comment: I got rid of the repetitive portions the assignments to the variables at the beginning and just used the ones in the function ```Width```. I agree with the focus on the integrations, but I do not know how I can simplify them. Do you have any suggestions? Not mathematically but using different functions in Mathematica maybe? I tried in an earlier version of my code to use NIntegral but it also takes so much time.

Comment: Copy your code into a fresh notebook and you will see that many variable in the three functions are blue.  These are undefined, and `With` used later does nothing to change that.  To assign values to these variables, they must be included in the function argument lists.  To see this try `With[{h1 = 1, p = 2, t1 = 2, r1 = 10}, rho1[r1, h1, t1]]`, which leaves `p` undefined.  It is difficult for me to give you much advice, because I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.